# ideavim :normal ex command not supported?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

I'm using pycharm and ideavim plugin for vim-like editing.

When I using :normal command, I was told "Not an editor command: normal"

Is there an alternative way to be done my work (for multi-lines run same macro), or there's a way to add normal command in ideavim?

Answer (score 7):

ideavim doesn't (yet) support `normal` command. But if you want to apply macro on multiple lines, you could add `j/k` , `+/-` or other linewise motions  in your macro, so that it will automatically process multiple lines.

E.g a simple macro: `dd`  to delete a line. If you added `j` -> `ddj` and do `x@y` it will delete `x` lines.

Comment: smart way, I've been tried before , but can be confused when I do a complex edition.(If I get last j forgot, I must record marco again.) And I must count myself for lines, annoying...

Comment: But this way you won't know how many times to run the macro and have to think too much about the number of times to run the macro. Instead it would be better to visual select the lines and then simply apply the macro like in normal vim.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: IdeaVim 1.9+ -> .ideavimrc -> `set noideadelaymacro`**

IdeaVim supports the normal command as of 1.9:
https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/pull/169#issuecomment-971393643

But it appears as though it isn't working fully yet, and so needs to be activated, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-830/Implement-the-normal-command#focus=Comments-27-5641084.0-0:

- "We've released IdeaVim 1.9.0 and, unfortunately, it doesn't have the :norm command enabled by default..."
- "...we've faced some issues in the IJ platform that break the experience of working with IdeaVim..."
- "...you can add `set noideadelaymacro` command into your ~/.ideavimrc. This will: Enable the :norm command..."

Comment: Thanks!! Was looking for a while and this is the first time I saw this mentioned. Works perfectly for my usecase of using norm for editing the endings of multiple different-sized lines at once: `:norm $x`